# Is it possible to use tc (traffic control) in linux to limit the upload speed?

Tags: bandwidth, linux

Is it possible (and not compromising to anonymity in a noticeable way) to use tc (traffic control) in linux to limit the upload speed into Tor (and not limit the download speed)?

Comment: What's your goal here? Why would you want to limit upload specifically?

Comment: Can any one tell the way. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  It's hard to tell how it will affect any of the anonymity properties.

I'm unclear why you would want to do that though.